# Kendo grid with client template breaks formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid (asp mvc) where the fields have a client template such that if the numeric value to be displayed is null it should display N/A instead. I also have formatting specified so that numbers have comma thousands separators and two decimal places. However the client template removes the formatting. Is there a way to have both?

An example column from the grid:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.RangeMin).Title("Range Min").ClientTemplate("#= RangeMin == null ? 'N/A' : RangeMin #").Format("{0:#,###.00}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling format after, call the `kendo.toString` method inside your `ClientTemplate` call, to avoid trying to format `'N/A'` as a number:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.RangeMin).Title("Range Min").ClientTemplate("#= RangeMin == null ? 'N/A' : kendo.toString(RangeMin, '#,###.00') #");
```

Comment: I came across this suggestion elsewhere after posting and tried it but it didn't work for me. It caused the page to stop rendering with an invalid client template exception. I had to use kendo.toString instead in the client template and specify the formatting there.

Comment: Ah nice, that was going to be my next suggestion, I'll adjust my answer for posterity sake.